# 404 when voting to delete from review queue

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

I voted to delete a Low Quality Post and got a 404 (on iPad, iOS 5.1). I was the third (and last one) to vote. This is the URL I got:

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15823606/vote/10?delete-main=&fkey=6fae277377713edb45d9c578a9a98797

This was the review:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1858271

Comment: That means its deleted

Comment: I have had the same problem and when I went on the original post, it wasn't deleted. Chrome 25 windows

Comment: Yes, exact dupe.

Comment: Repro again [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257045/upload-from-ios-app-to-amazon-s3/15824894#15824894) that **isn't** deleted. And [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1858763)

Comment: @HugoDozois Not for long :)

Comment: I got the 404 page too, when I voted to delete while [reviewing this](http://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/105129) (here's a [direct post link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110841/how-to-reset-zoneminder-password/278037#278037)). At that time--as well as now as I'm posting this comment--that question hasn't yet been deleted (though it does appear my delete vote was registered properly). Furthermore, I have over 10k reputation on Ask Ubuntu, so I shouldn't ever get a 404 page just from trying to access a post that's been deleted. This is definitely a bug, and probably very new.